# asp.net datareader

Tags: asp.net, dataset, dataadapter

I need to use DataSet ad DataAdapter with the below code but I cannot integrate it. Would you please help me add dataset and dataadapter to this.

```
DbCommand dbCommand10;
dbCommand10 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Select_Post_Comment");
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand10, "PostId", DbType.Guid, Post_ID);
//IDataReader dr10 = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// 1. setup command

// 2. add parameters

// 3. pass instance of command to data adapter
var da = new SqlDataAdapter( command );

// 4. create and fill a dataset (executes the command passed to the adapter)
var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill( ds );

// 5. be sure to dispose command/connection
```

- API reference (albeit with a rather poor example): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx
- [Other methods of populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)